# Colfusion Query results based on query results from a related table

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, cfquery

I am querying a table for all the available records. The results have a primary key called ticket_id

```
 <cfquery name="get_all_active_tickets">
  SELECT *
  FROM service_ticket
  where technician_id != <CFQUERYPARAM Value="#techID#"> AND technician_name != "" 
</cfquery>
```

The query returns 42 unique records, each record has a unique value for the column `ticket_id`.

I then want to query another another table for all records that also contain the primary key ticket_id and SUM a column in those results called service_qty for those related records. My goal is to add up all the values of service_qty for records that contains the same `ticket_id` value, and compare those values.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
<cfset IDs = valueList(get_all_active_tickets.ticket_id) >
<cfquery name="high_hours_tickets">
    select SUM(service_qty) as total, ticket_id
    from service_ticket_detail
    where ticket_id in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#IDs#" list="true">)
</cfquery>
```

However the results are not as expected. The record count for the query "high_hours_tickets" is only 1 and it looks like it is totaling the column 'service_qty' for all the records that are returned, not just the records that have the same ticket_id value.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

---

A solution that works, thanks to Ageax's contributions below:

```
<cfset IDs = valueList(get_all_active_tickets.ticket_id) >
<cfquery name="high_hours_tickets" datasource="#datasource#">        
    SELECT t.ticket_id, SUM( d.service_qty) AS totalQty
    FROM   service_ticket t 
    INNER JOIN service_ticket_detail d ON d.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
    WHERE   t.technician_id <> <cfqueryparam value="#techID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
    AND     t.technician_name <> "" 
    GROUP BY t.ticket_id
    HAVING  SUM( d.service_qty) > 2
</cfquery>

<cfoutput><cfset lstIDs = ValueList(high_hours_tickets.ticket_id) /></cfoutput>

<cfquery name="flagged_tickets" datasource="#datasource#">
    select * 
    from service_ticket
    where ticket_id IN ( 
        <cfqueryparam 
            value="#lstIDs#" 
            cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER"
            list="yes" 
            /> 
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `group by ticket_id`

Comment: Cool, that seemed to help. I put that group by clause on my second query. So if I wanted to sort through the second query I have to pull ticket_id values where the SUM result is greater than 2, would that be done with a QoQ?

Comment: Add `having total > 2`

Comment: In my where clause of query "high_hours_tickets"?

Comment: No, after the group by

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And it looks like your `flagged_tickets` query is pretty much duplicating your `high_hours_tickets`. Can you provide some sample data and expected output? In either case, I don't think you need your `valuelist()` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Since there was some confusion about the table structure and desired results, I put together a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) based on your description. It's a great tool for sharing schemas and sample data, and is helpful in avoiding a lot of back forth with query issues :-)  I don't know which version of MySQL you're using, so I'll assume an older version for best compatibility.

If I'm understanding correctly, the goal is to display all `service_ticket`  records, having an *overall* `service_qty` > 2.  To do that, use a subquery to SUM the `service_qty` values, by `ticket_id`, and drop any that are <= 2. Then join those results back to the main ticket table to get the details (name, address, etc...).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a104f4/2)

**Query:**

```
SELECT t.ticket_id
       , t.address
       , t.name
       -- ... additional columns
       , total.qty
FROM   service_ticket t INNER JOIN 
          (
             SELECT   ticket_id
                     , SUM( service_qty) AS Qty
             FROM   service_ticket_detail 
             GROUP BY ticket_id
             HAVING  Qty > 2
          ) 
          total ON total.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
WHERE   t.technician_id <> <cfqueryparam value="#techID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
AND     t.technician_name <> ''
```

---

**Original:**

Forget about the separate queries. This is a job for a JOIN. They're designed for just this purpose.

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, SUM( d.service_qty) AS totalQty
FROM   service_ticket t 
        INNER JOIN service_ticket_detail d ON d.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
WHERE   t.technician_id <> <cfqueryparam value="#techID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
AND     t.technician_name <> ''
GROUP BY t.ticket_id
HAVING  SUM( d.service_qty) > 2
```

IMO, JOIN's are indispensable. If you're unfamiliar with them, I'd strongly recommend reading a few [introductory tutorials on JOIN's](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/). You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm following the logic. So if I wanted to then filter the results of that query to output just the records where the value of 'totalQty' is >= 2, would I do a second query of query on those results?

Comment: No. You just add a `having` clause to the same query. See my updated answer.  BTW, although it could work by passing in a list of id's to a second query, the more id's you pass in, the slower the query. Plus most databases limit the number of id's to around 2000.  JOIN's are designed to do the same thing much more efficiently.

Comment: Awesome. That works. So if I wanted to output 't.ticket_id', would I refer to that as #t.ticket_id#?

Comment: Nope :-) Table/column aliases like "t" are only used by the database. All CF sees is the column name: "ticket_id". Just like in the original query.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I just need to loop through the results of the JOIN query for ticket_id?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want to display the totals, for each ticket_id, then yes, just use cfoutput query="..." as usual.

Comment: Well, my JOIN query now returns 3 records, the three records that totalQty is >= 2. I want to then run a query on the table service_ticket, refrencing ticket_id, of those three records. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Not quite :-) It'd probably save more iterations if you explained what information you're ultimately trying to display on the page, rather than describing it piece by piece. It sounds like you are working towards something bigger, but hard to say if you need 1 query or 5, without knowing what that is.

Comment: Ok, I'm doing a bad job of explaining this I know. The JOIN query that you helped with, pulls ticket_id from table service_ticket where the SUM of service_qty in the related table is greater than 2. Now that I have those 3 records, I want to query all the data from table service_ticket for those 3 records with the ticket_id. The output will be the all the data in that record (name, address, date, email etc...) I was thinking a second query that refrenced t.ticket_id would be the way to do it.

Comment: See my updated answer. For next time, be sure to include your MySQL version as there are some differences in the capabilities of MySQL 5.x vs 8.x.

Comment: okay will do. WhenI implement the new query, I get this error: Unknown column 'td.ticket_type' in 'field list'. Is this referring to the first select statement you think?

Comment: Also,  My table service_ticket_detail has two collumsn, ticket_id & service_qty and my table service_ticket has all the customer info data such as name, address, email, date used etc...

Comment: I find a round about way to get the answer I need using you original JOIN query with an additional query that parses the results. I up dated my original post.

Comment: Oh.. sorry, from the earlier description it sounded like they were in the detail table. There's a simpler way. **(Edit) See my updated answer.**